# Different font in ListView Android

Tags: android, list, listview, android-listview, fonts

I've a ListView:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

I build it:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("First");
list.add("Second");
ListView listFontView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listFontView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.textViewList, list));
        listFontView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

How can i do to set different font for any record of this arrayList of string?
I would use a font for "First" and another font for "Second".

Help me.
Thank you

Comment: I guess you have to use custom `ListView` to achieve this.

Comment: You need something like a custom ListAdapter for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easier or faster way to achieve what you ask for, but to do so, I made my own custom adapter.

For this purpose you can extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

This tutorial helped me a lot when I needed to make something similar.

[Creating a custom adapter](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

If you give it a shot this way, and you think you might need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` itself is not responsible for the look of its items. You use a `ListAdapter` for that. I suggest you watch [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&ei=7klZU5e1G87A7AaulYD4DA&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=SUp8wt1rFuGH0JUHIyVSUw) to understand how to make your own list adapters.